# Converting Varchar to Datetime using 'yyyymmdd' format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I am working with a date processing procedure. The dates that are coming in from a file are formatted as 'yyyymmdd' and need to be converted to a DATETIME data type for use with built in date functions such as dateadd or datepart.

CONVERT(DATETIME,datestring) - Throws an error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.'

I have thought about splitting the string into separate sections and recombining them to form a valid datetime stamp but would like to avoid this IF possible.

Any other ways to convert from this varchar format to a date or datetime?

Comment: can you provide the full SQL you are trying to execute as well as the argument values being supplied to CONVERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error your `datestring` may be stored as an `int`. You can convert it to a string and then convert it to a `datetime` type like so:

Try:

```
convert(datetime,convert(char(8),datestring))
```

or

```
convert(datetime2(2),convert(char(8),datestring))
```

---

Reference:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

Comment: Thank you this worked. I clearly have trouble reading error messages and will work on that. the final code I ended up using was : 

`code :
CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@nextdate))as 'nextdate';`

This successfully yielded a DATE type object from a string formatted as '20180628'

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is `try_convert()`, but that doesn't work in SQL Server 2008.  Instead, use `case`:

```
select (case when datestring between '17530101' and '99991212'
             then convert(datetime, datestring)
        end)
```